# Loop through all cells in Range using Interop

Tags: vb.net, interop, excel-interop

I want to loop through all cells in a range.

```
Dim rngTop, rngAll as Excel.Range
'Set a cell
rngTop = DirectCast(_sheet.Cells(1, 2), Excel.Range)
'Set a range from the Top cell to its last cell in the cells column
rngAll = rngTop.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)

    For Each cell As Excel.Range In rngAll
        If cell.Value2 = "x" Then
            'Do stuff
        End If
    Next
```

`cell.Value` is underlined and gives me the compil error that cell.value2 is an object and I cannot use an operator (= in this case) on it. Could anyone help me get this task accomplished? `Value2` should not be an object.

I also tried:

```
    Dim cell As Excel.Range = Nothing
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To rngAll.Rows.Count
        If DirectCast(rngAll.Cells(i, 5), Excel.Range).Value2 = "x" Then
        'Do stuff
        End If
    next i
```

but have the same problem as above.

Comment: Just a quick thought without trying more... What about `Cell.Value2.Tostring()`?

Comment: I think `Cell.Text` will work for you too.

Comment: dim cell as excel.range gives me an unknown typ, I guess I have to cast it into excel.range but I dont know how to do it in the context above. Cell.Text doesnt work, .Tostring at least doesnt give me a compile error but I have to test what comes out. If cell is of unknown type I guess .tostring doesnt give me the input of the cell. Gonne check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I have the solution. The problem here is that vb doesnt know what type value2 will deliver so it delivers an object. That is why the code give the message that the =-Operator cannot be applied. Using

```
If CStr(cell.value2) = "x" then
...
```

works perfect. So the best would be to write a function to check the valuetype for every possible type and convert it.